# Redirect from port 80 to 443 with nginx and multiple servers

Tags: nginx, ssl, redirect

To begin, I'm a bit new with nginx and a bit lost… I sadly didn't found any solution to this, so here is my problem. If it's a duplicate of an already existing question I apologize and I would be very pleased to see the answer.

I'm building my very first nginx server and I have two domain names, one of these has plenty of subdomains, and I wish to put a SSL redirect on all of these. Problem is that it works only once with a IPv6 listen (here on the default config), and nginx dosen't start if I put that same config on the other subdomains (each subdomain has its own server config file with its own 80 → 443 server redirect).

```
server {
listen 443;
listen [::]:443;

## All the config and stuff

}

server {
listen      80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
server_name www.mydomainna.me mydomainna.me;
rewrite     ^   https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

This is the default config file, and it works like a charm.

However and this is the thing that bugs me, is that on this exact same config (less the default_server) for every single subdomain and my second domain name I must remove IPv6 or nginx dosen't want to start.

```
server {
listen 443;
listen [::]:443;

## All the config and stuff

}

server {
listen      80;
server_name subdomain.mydomainna.me;
rewrite     ^   https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

So my question here is : how can I tell to listen on IPv6 for all of my other config files ?

I'm sorry if I didn't explained my question in a adequate manner and if anyone of you has a solution, thanks.

Comment: What is the error message nginx writes into the log when you try to start it with this configuration?

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, forgot to add it, here it is !  2016/04/10 18:15:48 [emerg] 14784#0: duplicate listen options for [::]:80 in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/seconddomainfile:line

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this page](http://kovyrin.net/2010/01/16/enabling-ipv6-support-in-nginx/) the line below tells Nginx to listen on port 80 for both IP4 and IP6.

```
listen [::]:80 default_server;
```

You have two directives telling Nginx to listen on port 443, which is why you're getting the duplicate listen message. Just remove the first line below and it should work.

```
listen 443;
listen [::]:443;
```

Note that I knew nothing about Nginx IP6 until I spent 2 minutes on Google. A very small amount of research uncovered this solution.